# Parse JSON to database in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON document like

```
{
    "obj": {
        "a": "x",
        "b": "y"
    },
    "arr": [
        {
            "c1": 11,
            "c2": 12,
            "c3": 13
        },
        {
            "c1": 21,
            "c2": 22,
            "c3": 23
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'd like to get it in Postgres database as

```
a b c1 c2 c3 
------------
x y 11 12 13 
x y 21 22 23
```

So far my code is

```
create table test(data json);
insert into test(data) values ('{"obj": {"a": "x","b": "y"},"arr": [{"c1": 11,"c2": 12,"c3": 13},{"c1": 21,"c2": 22,"c3": 23}]}')

select 
    (data -> 'obj' ->> 'a'),
    (data -> 'obj' ->> 'b'),
    (json_array_elements(data -> 'arr') ->> 'c1'),
    (json_array_elements(data -> 'arr') ->> 'c2'),
    (json_array_elements(data -> 'arr') ->> 'c3')
from test
```

Is there better solution than calling json_array_elements for each column?

btw. this JSON just a simplified example. In the actual JSON each object in array have more than 3 key/value pairs.

Comment: If you don't have PostgreSQL 15 available, then move your call to `jsonb_array_elements()` into the `from` section with a lateral join.

Comment: @nbk But you can't.  It was reverted from v15 and was never resubmitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to put the `json_array_elements` call into a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT
  data -> 'obj' ->> 'a',
  data -> 'obj' ->> 'b',
  j.val ->> 'c1',
  j.val ->> 'c2',
  j.val ->> 'c3'
FROM test, 
LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements(data -> 'arr')) j (val);

 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
 x        | y        | 11       | 12       | 13
 x        | y        | 21       | 22       | 23
(2 rows)
```